# Best tool for run commands on multiple server by single machine without login individually and see the log of command on master machine?

Tags: cloud, capistrano, cluster-computing, capistrano3

Please tell me the best tool for executing command on multiple system which have different OS.
And can we see the log of these command on a single machine.

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but it might be relevant on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Foldit. This is a well known example of this kind of crowd surfing where many computers contribute to folding a protein.

If you expect more help in the future, you need to show an attempt at the question.

But to get you started, all you really need is a bash-script that will ssh into several computers computer (assuming this is the same command/script over and over again on each computer).

- You'll need to rsync the script to each of the computers.
- You'll need to execute the script from ssh
- From ssh you can do a `tail -f` on the log file on each computer. This will tail separate log files. If you want them to be into one terminal window, you'll need to set up an infinite loop to rsync the log files to a directory for all of the log files. Best way is just to do the rsync, then sleep for a second or two, then rsync again. `tail -f *` will follow all log files in the directory.